# Simple way of sending data from appengine servlet to client asynchronously

Tags: java, google-app-engine, http, servlets, asynchronous

I created a Web Application who provides a service as a website.

I am planning to create a WebServlet API to allow other softwares (web or desktop) to easily integrate my service, calling simple actions as follows:

```
http://www.server_name.com/APIServlet?ACTION=CreateUser&DATA={"username":"username@gmail.com","password":"some_password"}
```

The problem is that the API should also provide a way of sending data asynchronously to API clients as soon as a given change happens.

I know that Channel API is the better way to achieve this, but it is quite complicated for API users to implement, specially in non javascript applications.

The better solution, in my opinion, requiring the less effort from API users would be "Long Polling", providing an API action that holds the response until the server has something to return or a "time out" occurs. Ex:

```
    http://www.server_name.com/APIServlet?ACTION=WaitMessage&DATA={"sessionId":"12kdj45jsdj"}
```

But AFAIK this solution isn't possible because appengine limits request responses to 30 seconds.

How could I implement asynchronous server -> client comunication using HTTP requests, in a simple way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only async server-to-client communication on GAE is available via [Channel API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/channel/overview). Unfortunately it's javascript only so you can only use it in browsers.

Comment: I am about to try XMPP. It isn't as simple as I would like, but at least it is more standard and independent from web browsers. I am considering to create a library that handles communication and share it with its source code. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

These are the different methods available

1. WebSockets  (Part of HTML5)
2. Long Polling and Commet
3. Polling

Using Websockets will be the easiest way. But for this to work we should ensure that client side browsers are latest and the server side also supports it. A new servlet called WebSocketServlet is available in tomcat 7.0.32 and above.

**PS: I am not sure if app engine is capable of websocket server side implementation.**

Long polling and polling are older methods. But they are still used because of browser compatibility issues.

You can use **Atmosphere framework** which contains a fall back mechanism for websockts , long polling and polling.